# Smart Unit Tests standalone

Tags: unit-testing, automated-tests, pex, parameterized-unit-test

I've been working with Smart Unit Tests (formerly Pex) for some time now. Pex had the ability to run as a standalone, command-line application which was really useful for several scenarios (e.g. extending the list of parameters of the Parameterized Unit Tests).

However, in the case of Smart Unit Tests (integrated in VS2015), I was not able to find a function to run it standalone (it only works with right clicking on the method to be analyzed). So, for example, when I want to extend the list of PUT parameters, I have to do it also in the method under test (which I really want to avoid) in order have it discovered by Smart Unit Tests.

So, my question is, that are there any possibilities to run Smart Unit Tests only from the generated PUT method like it was in Pex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the [VS 2015 RC build](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/prerelease-software-downloads-vs.aspx#AdditionalPageSections_14). You should be able to 'Run Intellitest' directly from the PUT.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, running an IntelliTest exploration is supported from both the code under test and from the generated PUT.

Please note that starting with the [VS 2015 RC build](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/prerelease-software-downloads-vs.aspx#AdditionalPageSections_14) "Smart Unit Tests" has been renamed to "IntelliTest".

Comment: Thank you, I've already tried it. It works great until I use Fakes within the PUT, which leads to an inner exception of the engine ([link](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1295096)).